# Dispatching captured events works but not when I've created them myself (HumanBenchmark)

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

So I've been trying to get the highest possible score on the [Typing test on HumanBenchmark](https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/typing) but ran into some oddities when trying to dispatch custom keybaordEvents.

I only got it working if I captured user inputs and then dispatched them again, but I don't understand why creating my own events won't work. HumanBenchmark don't seem to be checking the isTrusted flag since that is false in both scenarios.

Working code:

```
let vTarget = document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[0]
let vKeyEvents = {}
document.addEventListener("keydown", 
    function(e){
        vKeyEvents[e.key] = e
    }
);

function run(){
    vText = vTarget.innerText
    for (let index = 0; index < vText.length; index++) {
        vTarget.dispatchEvent(vKeyEvents[vText[index]])
    }
}
```

How to run my code ([Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyZi4MbQGCY)):

- Goto [HumanBenchmark Typing test](https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/typing)
- Paste the above code
- Click on anything in the dom except text box
- Press every letter on your keyboard including capitals and symbols used in the text.
- type run() in the console

##### Code I used for creating KeyboardEvents that isn't working

```
vTest = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', 
    {
        key:"t", 
        keyCode:84, 
        isComposing: true, 
        view:window
    });
document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[0].dispatchEvent(vTest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `bubbles: true` to the `KeyboardEvent` options

```
new KeyboardEvent('keydown', 
    {
        key:"t", 
        keyCode:84, 
        isComposing: true, 
        view:window,
        bubbles: true
    })
```

Comment: thank you, I would upvote if I could lol.